# MS Graph API Photo endpoint not working with App Permissions for Groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I´m trying to call MS Graph API to get the Photo from a Group using Application permissions, but I´m getting an "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

According to this link:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get

App permissions are supported:

For **user** resource:
User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All

For **group** resource:
Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All

I´m getting an App token, and I can see those permissions:

```
"roles": [
"User.ReadWrite.All",
"Group.Read.All",
"Group.ReadWrite.All",
"Directory.Read.All",
"User.Read.All" ]
```

Seems a bug in the Photo endpoint for Groups, as curiously, I can get any User photo using same App token. None of the Photo endpoints works for Groups:

```
/groups/{id}/photo
/groups/{id}/photo/$value
/groups/{id}/photos
```

Am I missing something? is there any other permission required (not documented).

In case anyone from MS product team can take a look, here is one of the error Ids:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ac884427-69ee-407e-b198-06bd6af5f4be",
            "date": "2018-10-30T13:12:19"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the request header? Based on you description, we couldn't find the problem.And I have tried those endpoint for Groups, it works fine

Comment: Thanks. You want the Bearer token too? Have you tried with Application permissions? cos works fine with delegated. Also, can´t you trace the request-id posted? I´ll post the request as soon as I can, but I don´t think there´s nothing in the request, as exactly the same one, but pointing to the User endpoint is working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same use case, apparently it seems that it's a known issue documented by Microsoft here : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/known-issues#permissions-for-groups-and-microsoft-teams

You must use a delegated permission and not an app permission.

> Examples of group features that support only delegated permissions:
>   Group conversations, events, photo
>   External senders, accepted or rejected senders, group subscription
>   User favorites and unseen count

Comment: Thanks a lot Arthur. I wasn't aware of that limitation. Funny to see how a guy that seems is from MS (kikang), is saying: "hey, I've tried those endpoints and work fine" ...

Comment: I guess he did not test the specific api calls impacted by this known issue. Nonetheless it's weird that the documentation does not redirect to the known issue page, it took me a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the subject, with app permissions the endpoint V1.0 does not work to get photo :

***Get** - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/photo/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/photo/$value)*

But it does work on beta endpoint :

***Get** - [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/photo/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/photo/$value)*

Nothing new on the **Put** call, cannot update a new group photo on V1.0 or beta endpoint.

The only way that I can update photo is really not secured, by using jwt Resource Owner Password Credentials.